# Returning correct .length even though length is 1

Tags: powershell

If I do a

```
$services = Get-Service
$services.length
```

I get 126 services. But if I specify one service

```
$services = Get-Service -Name vds
$services.length
```

I get nothing. This messes up loops I do in my script. How do I return the correct number from .length even though the length is 1 ?

With normal strings this is easy, I just specify as array:

```
$myarray = ,"one","two","three"
$myarray.length
```

would return 3, and

```
$myarray = ,"one"
$myarray.length
```

would return 1..

**How do I get the correct length returned?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you get nothing is because $services is no longer an array when you request 1 service by name.  You'll likely have to create the array and assign the service to element 0.

This works for me...

```
$services = @(Get-Service -Name vds)
```

Comment: Just for completeness, you can do the same as in you example: $services = ,(Get-Service -Name vds)

Comment: @CB The `@()` and `,` operators are not interchangeable, though in your example they do produce the same result since there can be at most one service with that name.  Consider the difference between `@(Get-Service -Name Lanman*)` and `,(Get-Service -Name Lanman*)`: the first produces an array with two elements, one for each service; the second produces an array with one element, and _that_ element is itself an array with two elements, one for each service.  `@()` means "turn this object into an array if it is not one already" and `,` means "unconditionally wrap this object in an array".