# Get-ChildItem.Length is Wrong

Tags: arrays, powershell, member-enumeration

I am writing a recursive function that goes through a directory and copies every file and folder in it. The first check I have in the function is to see if the path passed in has children. To find this out, I use the following method:

```
[array]$arrExclude = @("Extras")
Function USBCopy
{
Param ([string]$strPath, [string]$strDestinationPath)
    try
    {
        $pathChildren = Get-ChildItem -Path $strPath
        if($pathChildren.Length -gt 0)
        {
            foreach($child in $pathChildren)
            {
                if($arrExclude -notcontains $child)
                {
                    $strPathChild = "$strPath\$child"
                    $strDestinationPathChild = "$strDestinationPath\$child" 
                    Copy-Item $strPathChild -Destination $strDestinationPathChild
                    USBCopy $strPathChild $strDestinationPathChild  
                }   
            }
        }              
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error ("Error running USBCopy: " + $Error[0].Exception.Message)
    }    
}
```

For the most part my function works, but my code will say a directory is empty when it actually has 1 file in it. When I debug my function, the variable will say that the folder has children but the variable's length is 0. Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: `$pathChildren = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $strPath)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning correct .length even though length is 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701836/returning-correct-length-even-though-length-is-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$pathChildren.Count` instead of `$pathChildren.Length` - that will return the number of items in the array.

Comment: OP doesn't need to be using PSv2 to get a variable length of 0, an empty file would have the same result. Regardless, PetSerAl's suggestion of  `@(...)` and your answer expanding upon it is definitely a better practice to follow.

Comment: (Now) I think using `.Count` not only works just fine in PSv3+, it is arguably more idiomatic than `@(…).Length`, 
because it takes advantage of PSv3+'s unified handling of collections and scalars (though it's still worth understanding the underlying issues, especially that it is not an actual _array_ that `.Count` is invoked on here).

Answer (score 7):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as many times before, has provided the crucial pointer in a terse comment on the question (and he's also assisted in refining this answer):

```sh
$pathChildren = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $strPath)
```

The use of **`@(...)`, the *array subexpression operator*, ensures that whatever the enclosed command outputs is treated as an *array*, even if only *1* object is output**, so that `.Length` is guaranteed to be the *array*'s `.Length` property.

However, **in PSv3+, accessing `.Count` instead of `.Length`**, as in [WillPanic's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035455/45375), **works too** - see below.

Without `@(...)`, the result may be a *single* object, because PowerShell **automatically *unwraps* an output collection that contains only *1* object, which  yields *that one object only***, which implies the following:

- up to **PSv2**:

  - If that one object happens to have a `.Length` property, *its* values is returned.
    In the case at hand, this is true if the only object returned represents a *file* (a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instance) (which in turn is true if the directory contains exactly 1 file and no subdirectories, hidden items aside).
    A `[System.IO.FileInfo]`'s instance's `.Length` property returns *the file's size in bytes*.  A value of `0` implies an *empty file*.
    (If the only object returned had been a *directory* (a `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instance, `.Length` would have returned `$null`, because such instances don't have a `.Length` property.)
- **in PSv3+, the workaround is no longer strictly needed, if you use `.Count`**, because **you can treat even a *scalar* (single object) as if it *were* an array, with *implicit* `.Length` / `.Count`<sup>[1]</sup>
  properties and the ability to *index* into (e.g.,

  `<scalar>[0]`)** - these *implicit* members are known as **[*intrinsic* members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members)** - but there are ***caveats***:

  - If `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher is in effect, access to `.Length` and `.Count` properties that don't actually exist on a scalar at hand cause an *error*.
    This behavior is quite unfortunate, however, as these properties *should* be considered to exist *implicitly* - if you agree, make your voice heard in [GitHub issue #2798](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798).
  - **If the scalar *itself* has a property such as `.Length` or `.Count` or supports indexing, that takes precedence** - this is why `.Count` must be used in this case (as stated, `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances have a `.Length` property reporting the file size in bytes); see below for examples.
  - **Using `@(...)` avoids such collisions**, because the result is *always* an array.

    - **`@(...)`**, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) is **also necessary to work around a *bug* in *Windows PowerShell*** (as of the latest *and final* version, 5.1), which has since been corrected in [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md): **`[pscustomobject]` instances unexpectedly do *not* have `.Count` and `.Length` properties** (see [GitHub issue #3671](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3671) for the original bug report) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68355717/45375).
  - **Member-access enumeration** is the *complementary* aspect of unification, which allows you to apply a member (property or method) of the items *contained in* the collection *at the collection level*, in which case the member is implicitly *accessed on every item in the collection*, and the resulting values are returned as an *array*; see below for an example.
    To resolve name collisions with member-access enumeration, a different approach is needed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

---

#### Examples of PSv3+ unified collection handling

```sh
PS> (666).Length
1  # Scalar 666 was implicitly treated as a collection of length 1

PS> (666).Count
1  # Ditto - ** .Count is preferable, because it less often means something else **

# Caveat: A *string* scalar has a native .Length property
PS> ('666').Length; ('666').Count
3  # .Length: The string types's native property: the number of *characters*
1  # .Count: PowerShell's implicit collection handling: 1 *element*

PS> (666)[0]; (666)[-1]
666  # Index [0] always yields the scalar itself.
666  # Ditto for [-1], the *last* element.

# Member-access enumeration example: get the .Day property value from each
# [datetime] instance stored in an array.
PS> ((Get-Date), (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Day
20
19
```

---

<sup>[1] As PetSerAl points out, up to PSv5.1, an array's `.Count` property was an *alias* property of `.Length`, added by PowerShell's ETS (extended type system - see [`Get-Help about_Types.ps1xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml)).
However, this alias property hasn't really been needed since PSv3, when explicitly implemented .NET interface type members were exposed by PowerShell too, providing access to the array type's `ICollection.Count` property. v6 will therefore no longer have the alias property, at which point `.Count` will directly access `ICollection.Count` - see [GitHub issue #3222](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3222).

Note that PowerShell magic (i.e., an *intrinsic* member) is still involved when it comes to invoking `.Count` on a *scalar* (non-collection), however.</sup>