# Powershell command not working: removing lines from file1 that are in file2

Tags: windows, file, windows-7, powershell-2.0

I am using the following code to remove lines from `file1.txt` that are in `file2.txt`.

```
powershell -Command "$(Get-Content file1.txt) | Where-Object {$_ -notIn $(Get-Content file2.txt)}"
```

But I'm getting an error regarding -notIn, looking for a value expression.  But `file2.txt` does exist and is not null.

What is causing the error, and how to fix it?

Comment: PowerShell version?

Comment: @PetSerAl Version 2

Comment: `-in` and `-notin` are v3+

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks.  If at all possible, I need to keep it compatible with what is installed with Windows 7 Pro by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement [LotPings' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44609261/45375):

- For *execution speed*, do not execute `Get-Content file2.txt` in *every loop iteration* - cache its result beforehand.
- For *memory efficiency*, do not collect all lines of `file1.txt` *up front* with `$(...)` before sending them through the pipeline.

Therefore (I'm omitting the `powershell -Command "..."` wrapper for brevity):

```powershell
$f2 = Get-Content file2.txt; Get-Content file1.txt | Where-Object { $f2 -NotContains $_ }
```

---

> Which $ are necessary, and why?

**`(...)`** and **`$(...)`** (the subexpression operator) and **`@(...)`** (the *array* subexpression operator) all **collect the entire command's / commands' output *as a whole***, in an *array* (`[System.Object[]]`), except if the output comprises only *1* item, in which that item *itself* is returned.

`(...)`, which can only enclose a *single* command or expression, is needed:

- to clarify precedence in an expression,
- to use a command (cmdlet / function / external utility call ) as part of an expression.
- In a pipeline, you can use it to force collecting the enclosed command's entire output *beforehand*, but doing so negates the memory-throttling benefit of a pipeline.

  - That said, using something like `(Get-Content file) | ... | Set-Content file` enables updating a given file `file` "in-place" - but do note that this requires the entire contents of `file` to fit into memory.
- Unless you have additional requirements as stated below, prefer `(...)` to `$(...)` and `@(...)`.

`$(...)` is only needed: <sup>Tip of the hat to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for his help.</sup>

- to enclose *statements* such as `if` and `foreach`
- to enclose *multiple* commands/expressions/statements
- to embed the above *inside `"..."`* (a double-quoted string, whose contents are subject to *interpolation* (expansion)).
  Among the operators listed, `$(...)` is the *only* one that can (directly) be embedded inside a double-quoted string.
- `$(...)` - unlike `(...)` - doesn't abort the entire command if a *potentially terminating* error occurs; e.g.:

  - `'hi' + $(1/0)` and `"hi$(1/0)"` report the division-by-zero error, yet still print `hi`; by contrast, `'hi' + (1/0)` does not - the division-by-zero error aborts the entire expression.
  - Note that an *unconditionally terminating* error even aborts any `$(...)`-containing expression; e.g., `'hi' + $(Throw 'err')` and `"hi$(Throw 'err')"` both only print the error message, not also `hi`.

`@(...)` is only needed:

- to ensure that a command's output is an *array*, even if only *1* item is returned; in other respects, it acts like `$()`, except that you cannot use it inside `"..."`; for a detailed discussion of `@()`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375) of mine.
- In PSv3+, the unified handling of scalars and arrays *typically* makes `@(...)` unnecessary, however - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) of mine.

Comment: Wow!  I'm carefully reading every word you wrote.  Thank you!

Comment: That's about a 400% speed increase! :)

Comment: @PetSerAl: I get what you're saying, but then it's not a true _terminating_ error: try `'hi' + $(throw "me")`, for instance. Expressions such as `1/0` and .NET method calls such as `[int]::Parse('foo')` occupy this strange middle ground between terminating and non-terminating errors. My personal preference: DO make them truly terminating errors. In the meantime: what do we call these terminating-under-some-circumstances errors?

Comment: I am not sure why you call `1/0` not a true terminating error, because them behave exactly as if cmdlet call to `ThrowTerminatingError` method: `Add-Type 'using System.Management.Automation; [Cmdlet("Throw", "TerminatingError")] public class ThrowTerminatingErrorCmdlet : Cmdlet { protected override void EndProcessing() { ThrowTerminatingError(new ErrorRecord(new System.Exception(), "Error", ErrorCategory.NotSpecified, null)); } }' -PassThru | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Assembly | Import-Module`.

Comment: And `(Write-Host Before)+(Throw-TerminatingError)+(Write-Host After); 'Next statement'` vs `(Write-Host Before)+(1/0)+(Write-Host After); 'Next statement'`, or `try { Write-Host Before; Throw-TerminatingError; Write-Host After } catch [int] { 'Error not handled so this is not printed' }; 'Next statement'` vs `try { Write-Host Before; 1/0; Write-Host After } catch [int] { 'Error not handled so this is not printed' }; 'Next statement'`. IMHO, `throw` is just a special case which is more terminating then standard terminating errors.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Your examples are very helpful as usual, but there must still be something I'm not getting about the distinction between the error generated by `1/0`, for instance, vs. `throw`. The documentation doesn't help. I'll open a GitHub issue.

Answer (score 1):

For PowerShell v2 reverse the arguments and use `-NotContains`

```
powershell -Command "$(Get-Content file1.txt) | Where-Object {$(Get-Content file2.txt) -NotContains $_ }
```

[Reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112964)

Comment: Thank you!  Which $ are necessary, and why?  (I can ask a separate question, if you like.)

Comment: Only tthe `$_` is required the `$` prepending the opening parenthesis aren't necessary.