# Objects with no '.Count' Property - use of @() (array subexpression operator) vs. [Array] cast

Tags: arrays, powershell, scalar, powershell-cmdlet, cim

I am trying to perform some simple if statements, but all of the newer cmdlets that are based upon [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance] don't seem to expose a .count method?

```
$Disks = Get-Disk
$Disks.Count
```

Doesn't return anything. I found that I can cast this as an [array], which makes it returns a .NET .count method as expected.

```
[Array]$Disks = Get-Disk
$Disks.Count
```

This works without directly casting it as an array for previous cmdlets:

```
(Get-Services).Count
```

What is the recommended way to get around this?

An example that doesn't work:

```
$PageDisk = Get-Disk | Where {($_.IsBoot -eq $False) -and ($_.IsSystem -eq $False)}
  If ($PageDisk.Count -lt 1) {Write-Host "No suitable drives."; Continue}
   Else If ($PageDisk.Count -gt 1) {Write-Host "Too many drives found, manually select it."}
   Else If ($PageDisk.Count -eq 1) { Do X }
```

Option A (Cast as Array):

```
[Array]$PageDisk = Get-Disk | Where {($_.IsBoot -eq $False) -and ($_.IsSystem -eq $False)}
  If ($PageDisk.Count -lt 1) {Write-Host "No suitable drives."; Continue}
   Else If ($PageDisk.Count -gt 1) {Write-Host "Too many drives found, manually select it."}
   Else If ($PageDisk.Count -eq 1) { Do X }
```

Option B (Use Array Indexes):

```
 $PageDisk = Get-Disk | Where {($_.IsBoot -eq $False) -and ($_.IsSystem -eq $False)}
  If ($PageDisk[0] -eq $Null) {Write-Host "No suitable drives."; Continue}
   Else If ($PageDisk[1] -ne $Null) {Write-Host "Too many drives found, manually select it."}
   Else If (($PageDisk[0] -ne $Null) -and (PageDisk[1] -eq $Null)) { Do X }
```

Option C (Array) -Thanks to @PetSerAl :

```
$PageDisk = @(Get-Disk | Where {($_.IsBoot -eq $False) -and ($_.IsSystem -eq $False)})
  If ($PageDisk.Count -lt 1) {Write-Host "No suitable drives."; Continue}
   Else If ($PageDisk.Count -gt 1) {Write-Host "Too many drives found, manually select it."}
   Else If ($PageDisk.Count -eq 1) { Do X }
```

What is the reason for CIM based cmdlets not exposing the .Count method? What is the recommended way to handle this? Option B seems convoluted to me, and hard to read. Option A works, but shouldn't powershell cast this as an array for me? Am I going about this in entirely the wrong way?

Comment: `$Result = @(Your command here)`

Comment: `(Get-Services).Count` works because `Get-Services` returns multiple objects. If you need an array (of potentially 0 or 1 object(s)), then use the array sub-expression operator (`@(...)`) as suggested by @PetSerAl above

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks. Isn't that exactly the same as [Array]$Result = Command_Here ?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks! I was under the impression that pretty much everything in powershell was setup to handle multiple objects? Even "(10*2).Count" works. What determines whether the object built can handle mutliple or single objects?

Comment: @CobyCode No, them are different: `[Array]$a = &{}; $b = @(&{}); $a.GetType(); $b.GetType()` or `[Array]$a = New-Object Object[] 10; $b = @(New-Object Object[] 10); $a.Count; $b.Count` or `[Array]$a = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Object]; $b = @(New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Object]); $a.Count; $b.Count`.

Comment: @PetSerAl That took me a while to figure out! I also found some further information from this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355649/array-types-in-powershell-system-object-vs-arrays-with-specific-types) which it looks like you also had a hand in answering. I can see that they are different, but still not entirely sure what the difference is. .GetType() shows a basetype of system.array for both of them. Also: Can you write up as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**In PSv3+, with its unified handling of scalars and collections, *any* object -  even `$null` - *should* have a `.Count` property** (and, with the exception of `$null`, should support indexing with `[0]`).

**Any occurrence of an object *not* supporting the above should be considered a *bug***; for instance:

- Using this [*intrinsic* (engine-supplied)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/5627) **`.Count` property *unexpectedly fails* when  [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode)`-Version 2` or higher is in effect**, which is a long-standing bug reported in [GitHub issue #2798](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798), still present as of PowerShell 7.2 (whereas a *type-native* `.Count` property, such as on an array, *can* safely be accessed).
- (`[pscustomobject]` instances not playing by these rules was a [known bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3671), [fixed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/5745) in 2017).

Since I don't know if said bug is related to the `[Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Disk]` instances that `Get-Disk` outputs, and since `Get-Disk` - at least currently - is only available in *Windows PowerShell*, I encourage you to file a separate bug on [uservoice.com](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell).

**Use of array-subexpression operator `@(...)` is *only* necessary**:

- as a ***workaround*** for the bug at hand / the `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` bug.
- **in case a *scalar* object happens to have its *own* `.Count` property**.

---

**Generally**,

- If you do need to ensure that **output from a *command*** is captured as an array, **`@(...)`** is the PowerShell-idiomatic, more concise, and syntactically easier form compared to `[Array] ...` / `[object[]] ...`
- By contrast, capturing **output from an *expression*** may call for `[Array] ...` / `[object[]] ...`, to avoid the potential inefficiency of *enumerating* expression output that already *is* an array and collecting it in a *new* array - see below for details.
- With either type of output, as in your question, **you may use `[Array]` as a *type constraint* on a variable** (placed to the *left* of it), so as to ensure that *later assignments* too are treated as arrays; a contrived example: `[Array] $a = 1` stores `1` wrapped in a (single-element) `[object[]]` array, and a later `$a = 2` assignment implicitly does that for `2`.

Additionally, **`@(...)` and `[Array] ...` are *typically*, but not *always* equivalent**, as [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)'s helpful examples in a comment on the question demonstrate; to adapt one of his examples:

`@($null)` returns a single-item array whose one and only element is `$null`, whereas `[Array] $null` has no effect (stays `$null`).

This behavior of `@()` is consistent with its purpose (see below): since `$null` is not an array, `@()` wraps it in one (resulting in a `[System.Object[]]` instance with `$null` as the only element).

In PetSerAl's other examples, `@()`'s behavior with `New-Object`-created arrays and collections - may be surprising - see below.

---

#### The purpose of `@(...)` and how it works:

The **purpose of `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--)**, is, loosely speaking, to **ensure that the result of an expression/command is treated as an *array***, even if it happens to be a *scalar* (single object).:

- **`@(...)` collects an enclosed **command's** output *as-is* / an enclosed *expression's* *enumerated* output in an - *always new* - `[object[]]` array**, even if there's only a *single* output object.

  - As such, **`@()` is merely a slight modification** - for the single-object output case - **of PowerShell's *default behavior* with respect to collecting command and expression output from its *success output stream*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71641785/45375) for more information. In short, single-object output is by default collected *as-is*, whereas `@()` wraps it in an array (by contrast, *multiple* output objects *always* get collected in an array, in *both* cases, of necessity).<sup>Tip of the hat to [Slawomir Brzezinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4356868/slawomir-brzezinski) for helping to clarify.</sup>
- **`@(...)` is never *needed* for array *literals*** (in v5.1+ it is optimized away) - use of **`,`**, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) by itself is generally sufficient, e.g., `'foo', 'bar'` instead of `@('foo', 'bar')` - but you **may prefer it for *visual clarity***; it is also **useful in the following cases**:

  - to create an *empty* array: `@()`)
  - to create a *single-element* array - e.g. `@('foo')` - which is easier to read than the *unary* form of `,` that would otherwise be required - e.g. `, 'foo'`
  - for *syntactic convenience*: to spread what is conceptually an array literal across multiple lines without having to use `,` to separate the elements and without having to enclose commands in `(...)`; e.g.:

    ```
    @(
      'one'
      Write-Output two
    )
    ```
- **Pitfalls**:

  - **`@()` is not an array *constructor*, but a "guarantor"**: therefore, `@(@(1,2))` does *not* create a nested array:

    - `@(@(1, 2))` is effectively the same as `@(1, 2)` (and just `1, 2`). In fact, each additional `@()` is an *expensive no-op*, because it simply creates a *copy* of the array output by the previous one.
    - Use the unary form of `,` the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), to construct nested arrays:
      `, (1, 2)`
  - `$null` is considered a *single object* by `@()`, and therefore results in a single-element array with element `$null`:

    - `@($null).Count` is `1`
  - *Command* calls that output *a single array as a whole* result in a *nested* array:

    - `@(Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2).Count` is `1`
  - In an *expression*, wrapping *a collection of any type* in `@()` *enumerates* it and invariably collects the elements in a (new) `[object[]] array`:

    - `@([System.Collections.ArrayList] (1, 2)).GetType().Name` returns `'Object[]'`

Read on for more detailed information, if needed.

---

**Details**:

`@()` behaves as follows: <sup>Tip of the hat to PetSerAl for his extensive help.</sup>

- In **PSv5.1+** (Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell [Core] 6+), using **an expression that *directly* constructs an array** using **`,`**, the [array *constructor* operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), **optimizes `@()` away**:

  - E.g., `@(1, 2)` is the same as just `1, 2`, and `@(, 1)` is the same as just `, 1`.
  - In the case of an array constructed with *just* `,` - which yields a `System.Object[]` array - this optimization is helpful, because it saves the unnecessary step of first unrolling that array and then repackaging it (see below).
    Presumably, this optimization was prompted by the widespread and previously inefficient practice of using `@( ..., ..., ...)` to construct arrays, stemming from the mistaken belief that `@()` is needed to construct an array.
  - However, in **Windows PowerShell v5.1 *only***, the **optimization is *unexpectedly* also applied when constructing an array with a *specific type* using a *cast***, such as `[int[]]` (the behavior has been corrected in **PowerShell [Core] 6+ and older Windows PowerShell versions are *not* affected**); e.g.,
    `@([int[]] (1, 2)).GetType().Name` yields `Int32[]`. This is the only situation in which `@()` returns something *other* than `System.Object[]`, and assuming that it always does **can lead to unexpected errors and side effects**; e.g.:
    `@([int[]] (1, 2))[-1] = 'foo'` breaks.
    `$a = [int[]] (1, 2); $b = @([int[]] $a)` unexpectedly doesn't create a *new* array - see [GitHub issue #4280](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4280).
- **Otherwise:** If the (first) statement inside `@(...)` is an *expression* that happens to be an *enumerable*,<sup>[1]</sup> it is enumerated, i.e. its elements are sent *one by one* to the success output stream; a *command*'s (typically one-by-one streaming) output is collected as-is; in either case **the resulting count of objects determines the behavior**:

  - **If the result is a *single* item / contains *no* items**, the result is **wrapped in a single-element / empty array of type `[System.Object[]]`**.

    - E.g., `@('foo').GetType().Name` yields `Object[]` and `@('foo').Count` yields `1` (though, as stated, in PSv3+, you can use `'foo'.Count` directly).
      `@( & { } ).Count` yields `0` (executing an empty script block outputs a "null collection"
      (`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`)
    - *Caveat*: **`@()` around a `New-Object` call that creates an array / collection outputs that array/collection *wrapped in a single-element outer array***.

      - `@(New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList).Count` yields `1` - the empty array list is wrapped in a single-element `System.Object[]` instance.
      - The reason is that `New-Object` outputs the list *as a single object* (that just so happens to be an enumerable itself), array/collection), causing `@()` to wrap it in a single-item array.
      - What may be confusing is that this does *not* happen when you use an *expression* to construct an array / a collection, because the expression's output is *enumerated* (an operation sometimes also called unwrapping or unrolling):

        - `@([system.collections.arraylist]::new()).Count` yields `0`; the expression outputs an empty collection that is enumerated, and since there's noting to enumerate, `@()` creates an empty `System.Object[]` array.
          Note that, in **PSv3+**, simply using an extra set of parentheses (`(...)`) with `New-Object` - which converts the `New-Object` *command* to an *expression* - would yield the same result:
          `@((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList)).Count` yields `0` too.
  - **If the result comprises *multiple* items**, these items are returned  as a **regular PowerShell array (`[System.Object[]]`)**; e.g.:

    - With a *command*:

      - `$arr = @(Get-ChildItem *.txt)` collects the one-by-one streaming output from `Get-ChildItem` in a `System.Object[]` array
    - With an *expression*:

      - `$arr = [int[]] (1, 2); @($arr)` *enumerates* `[int[]]` array `$arr` and then *repackages* the elements as a `System.Object[]` array.
      - Note the *inefficiency* and *potential loss of type fidelity* of this process: the original array is *enumerated* and collected in a *new* array that is always of type `System.Object[]`; the ***efficient alternative* is to cast to `[array]`** (which also works with *commands*): `[array] $result = ...`

---

<sup>[1] For a summary of which types PowerShell considers enumerable - which both excludes select types that do implement `IEnumerable` and includes one that doesn't - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375).</sup>

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. But then what is the preferred way to get around this? If I use $a = @(...) , later, when I have use the value of $a, it doesn't work when I am using it as an input on some other cmldet that is expecting a system.object[] ... so '$disk = @(get-disk); new-volume $disk'  will fail. I guess I could use 'new-volume $disk[0]' or '$disk=disk[0]; new-volume $disk' ....

Comment: Also, to note, I seem to be getting this for all cmdlets that are built upon [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance]

Comment: @CobyCode: `$disk = @(get-disk)` indeed returns a `[System.Object[]]` instance, which you can verify with `Get-Member -InputObject $disk`. From what I can tell, `New-Volume`'s first positional parameter is a _scalar_ type, so trying to pass it a `[System.Object[]]` instance is expected to fail; see `New-Volume -?`.

Comment: @mklement0 This might be just the most clearly written comment I have ever seen (with the exception of your other answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355649/array-types-in-powershell-system-object-vs-arrays-with-specific-types/42373523#42373523) . Thank you! As per your suggestion, I am going to submit this to uservoice.

Comment: @SlawomirBrzezinski, to bring closure to this exchange: Thank you for encouraging me to improve the answer and for bringing clarity to how `@()` is related to the default success output-stream behavior. Given the focus of this answer, I think my update is the appropriate way to reflect this (I just updated to give you a little shout-out). If you agree, I suggest we clean up our comments here (I've already removed my previous ones).

Comment: @SlawomirBrzezinski, thanks, but I think the slight-modification angle is the better way to frame it, because that's exactly what it is: it builds on the default behavior by wrapping collected output that comprises a single object only in an array (too). That is, it doesn't matter whether that single object happens to be an enumerable or not, which contradicts your comment, if I read it correctly.

Comment: As for `, $array` vs. `@(Write-Output -NoEnumerate $array)`: Performance differences and [other weirdness resulting from _cmdlet_ use](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579) aside, this comes down to a matter of taste. Yes, unary `,` is obscure _at first_, but on a general note I don't think language features should be avoided just because they may be unfamiliar to users coming from other languages.

Comment: Let's continue the discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243389/discussion-between-slawomir-brzezinski-and-mklement0) you've previously tried to initiate.

Answer (score 2):

@mklement0 has a great answer, but one thing to add: if your script (or the script calling yours) has [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode), the automatic `.Count` and `.Length` properties stop working:

```
$ Set-StrictMode -off
$ (42).Length
1
$ Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$ (42).Length
ParentContainsErrorRecordException: The property 'Length' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
```

To be safe, you can wrap any unknown variable in an array `@(...)` before checking the length:

```
$ $result = Get-Something
$ @($result).Length
1
```

Comment: Thanks, and good point - I've also updated my answer. This bug has been around for a long time, and was notably filed by Jeffrey Snover himself - see [GitHub issue #2798](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798).