# How does Powershell array flattening work?

Tags: arrays, powershell

Please, observe:

```
C:\> $x = @(1)
C:\> $x = @($x,2)
C:\> $x = @($x,3)
C:\> $x = @($x,4)
C:\> $x = @($x,5)
C:\> $x.Length
2
C:\> @($x |% { $_ }).Length
3
C:\> $x


Length         : 2
LongLength     : 2
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {System.Object[] 2, 3}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 2

4
5


C:\>
```

I expected the pipeline to flatten the list. But it does not happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, right off hand I would say that it is because you are just adding dimensions to the array that is the first element of $x and Powershell probably only goes one dimension deep to flatten.

Comment: PowerShell only flattens arrays with one item: `@(@(@("Test"))).Length`, returns: `1` and `@(@(@("Test")))[0].GetType()`, returns: `String`. In other words: `@(@(@("Test"))) <=> @("Test")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I expected the pipeline to flatten the list.

- PowerShell *enumerates* arrays (lists) and, generally speaking, (most) *enumerable* data types, i.e. it sends their elements *one by one* to the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) (for which the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) acts as a conduit).

  - If an element itself happens to be another enumerable, it is *not* also enumerated.
  - **Conceptualizing output in PowerShell as *object streams of indeterminate length* is better than to think of it in terms of *arrays* (lists) and their *flattening* - see the bottom section.**
- Separately, *during for-display formatting only*, enumerables are enumerated *two* levels deep, so that *visually* you can't tell the difference between `@(1, 2)` (an array that is enumerated, resulting in two integers being output) and `Write-Output -NoEnumerate @(1, 2)` (an array that is output *as a single object*) - even though in terms of *data* output these commands differ.

  - This for-display-only nested enumeration stops at the second level, so that any element at that level is formatted *as it itself*, even if it happens to be yet *another* enumerable; e.g., in the case of an array, that array is formatted according to the usual PowerShell rules for a given object: because the .NET [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array) type has more than 4 properties, [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) formatting is implicitly applied, resulting in a line-by-line display of `Array` instance's properties, as shown in the following example:

    ```sh
    # The 2nd element - a nested array - is formatted as a whole.
    PS> Write-Output -NoEnumerate @(1, @(2))
    1

    Length         : 1
    LongLength     : 1
    Rank           : 1
    SyncRoot       : {2}
    IsReadOnly     : False
    IsFixedSize    : True
    IsSynchronized : False
    Count          : 1
    ```

Applying the above to your specific example:

```sh
# Your nested array.
$x = @(1); $x = @($x,2); $x = @($x,3); $x = @($x,4); $x = @($x,5)
```

To visualize the resulting nested array, pass it to [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json):

```sh
PS> ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 $x

[
  [
    [
      [
        [
          1
        ],
        2
      ],
      3
    ],
    4
  ],
  5
]
```

This tells us that you've created a *two*-element array, whose first element happens to be a nested array, itself comprising two elements, the first of which contains another nested array.

- Therefore, `$x.Length` outputs `2`.
- `@($x | % { $_ }).Length` outputs `3` for the following reason:

  - Sending `$x` to the pipeline operator `|` enumerates its elements, and outputting each element (via `$_` in the `%` (`ForEach-Object`) script  block) causes each element to *also* be enumerated, if it happens to be an array.
  - Thus, the elements of the two-element array nested inside the first element of `$x` were output individually, followed by `5`, the second element of `$x`, resulting in a total of *three* output objects.
  - Capturing these output objects in an array (`@(...)`) creates a three-element array whose `.Length` reports `3`.

The for-display representation resulting from outputting `$x` itself follows from the explanation above.

---

#### Background information:

- **The [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) is a conduit for the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), which is a *stream* of objects of *indeterminate* length, and only when that stream is *captured*** - in the context of *assigning to a variable* (`$var = ...`) or making command output *participate in an expression* (e.g. `(...).Foo`) - **does the concept of *arrays* enter the picture:**

  - If the output stream happens to contain just *one* object, that object is captured *as-is*.
  - Otherwise, the PowerShell engine - of necessity - captures the multiple objects in a *collection*, which is an *`[object[]]`-typed array*.
- Thus, **the output stream has *no* concept of arrays, and it ultimately leads to confusion to discuss it in term of *arrays* and their *flattening*.**

  - Note that the **output stream (a pipeline)** isn't only used when using the [pipeline *operator* (`|`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#pipeline-operator-) to explicitly pipe data *between* commands, ...
  - ... it is **also used *implicitly* by *any single command*** to send its output to.
  - However, it is *not* used in an *expression* (alone), such as `1 + 2` or `[int[]] (1, 2, 3)` (a *command* is any cmdlet, function, script, script block, or external program) or when passing *arguments* to commands.

    - That said, if you send the result of an expression to a command via `|` (which only works if the expression is the *first* pipeline segment), a pipeline is again involved, and the usual enumeration behavior (discussed below) applies to the expression's result; e.g. `[int[]] (1, 2, 3) | ForEach-Object { 1 + $_ }`
    - Perhaps surprisingly, use of the [`@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) and [`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) operators *invariably* involves a pipeline, so that even enclosing stand-alone expressions in them results in enumeration (and re-collection); e.g., `@([int[]] (1, 2, 3)).GetType().Name` reports `Object[]` (`[object[]]`), because the strongly typed `[int[]]` array was enumerated, and the results were collected in a regular PowerShell array.
      The only exceptions are array *literals* such as `@(1, 2, 3)`, where (in PowerShell version 5 and above) this behavior is optimized away.
      By contrast, the [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) operator does *not* enumerate expression results.
- By default, **outputting an *array*** to the success output stream (more generally, instances of *most* .NET types that implement the **[`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) interface**<sup>[1]</sup>), **causes it to be *enumerated*, i.e. its *elements* are sent *one by one***.

  - As such, there is no guaranteed relationship between outputting an array and whether or not capturing the output also results in an (new) array.
  - Notably, outputting a single object is indistinguishable from outputting that single object wrapped in a (single-element) array.
- **Sending arrays (collections) *as a whole* to the pipeline requires additional effort**:

  - *Either* use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) `-NoEnumerate`

    ```sh
    # -> 1, because only *one* object was output, the array *as a whole*
    (Write-Output -NoEnumerate @(1, 2) | Measure-Object).Count
    ```
  - *Or* - more obscurely, but more efficiently, use the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), in order to wrap an array in an *aux., transitory array* whose enumeration then outputs the original array as a single object:

    ```sh
    (, @(1, 2) | Measure-Object).Count # -> 1
    ```

---

<sup>[1] For a summary of which types PowerShell considers enumerable - which both excludes select types that do implement `IEnumerable` and includes one that doesn't - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375).</sup>