# Get lines of Strings into an "array"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have often lines of strings in VSCode, but would need an array for PowerShell or SQL.

I have in VSCode

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I would need somthing like that in Vscode

```
('line1','line2','line3')
```

Resulting in

```
Select * from Table where Column in ('line1','line2','line3')
```

or

```
$a = 'line1','line2','line3'
```

Is there an function / extension for this?

Comment: It's unclear what your are trying to achieve. You said you work in VScode but want an array for powershell or sql... What's the relation ?

Comment: Do you want a script that transformes a couple of pasted lines (or the content of a file) into a powershell object of type array?

Comment: I could script it, but I find it tedious. You can also edit it with several cursors - but sometimes there are 20 elements. So i would love to mark the part and click 'transform' :)

Comment: Made it clearer, I hope. Have to improve myself here.

Comment: Good question; an aside: Please don't use `@(...)` for array literals - not only is it unnecessary, it is inefficient in PowerShell versions up to 5.0, but, more importantly, it invites conceptual confusion by falsely suggesting that it _constructs_ arrays - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375).

Comment: Thanks for you input - changed my example to spread the word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: array build demo]You could make a snippet that'll do this easily. Add a keybinding to trigger that snippet in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "alt+b",                             // or whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s*(.+)(\\s)?/'$1'${2:+,}/g})"
  }
}
```

`${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s*(.+)(\\s)?/'$1'${2:+,}/g}` get the selected text.
The regex will get the text of each line in capture group 1, and any newline character in capture group 2.

Then `'group 1'` is added followed by a `,` only if there is a group 2.  Because of the `g` regex flag this will happen for all lines.

---

If you want empty lines to be represented as an empty strings in your output, use

```
  "snippet": "(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/((.+)(\\r\\n))|(.+)|(\\r\\n)/'$2$4'${3:+,}${5:+,}/g})"
```

Demo of this:

[image: empty lines demo]

---

If you want this output of the snippet:

`Select * from Table where Column in ('line1','line2','line3')`

then use:

```
"snippet": "Select * from Table where Column in (${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\s*(.+)(\\s)?/'$1'${2:+,}/g})"
```

Comment: Nicely done; for a strictly line-oriented transformation where you don't need to worry about having a trailing newline in the selection, use `"(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.+)(\\n(?=\\S))?/'$1'${2:+,}/g})"`

Comment: Really like this! Wanted to improve it, so in a PowerShell file VSCode will do the PowerShell line and in SQL Files there will be the select - but it seems that keyboard bindings cannot be bound to a filetype yet. Thx again.

Comment: Did not get the solution from @mklement0 to run properly, because in my test it failed to create the comma ",". And I really have to improve my regular expression skills.

Comment: @theq, I forgot about CRLF line feeds; try `"(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.+)(\\r?\\n(?=\\S))?/'$1'${2:+,}/g})"`

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks again! - Works better, but if you have a newline in the data rows there will stay a newline in the result. Any way to convert this to an empty string like ''?

Comment: I am a little confused.  What does the alternative input look like that you are worried about?

Comment: @theq, try `"(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(.+|(?=\\r?\\n[^]))(\\r?\\n(?!$))?/'$1'${2:+, }/g})"`

Comment: The above works for me and converts empty line to empty string. great. @mklement0

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using regex replace:

- Select lines of code you wish to join
- ctrl+h, change mode to Regular Expressions
- in Find type \n
- in Replace type '),('
- Replace All

There's no need to add `\r` in Find or escape parenthesis in Replace.

[image: screen]

Comment: That's quite near to perfect.

Comment: @theq then why I am the first person upvoting it?