# Loop trough multiple SharePoint site collections

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Currently I have this script:

```
$SiteURL="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso"
$UserID="j.doe@contoso.nl"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential

#Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Site
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credential $cred

#sharepoint online powershell remove user permissions from site collection
Get-SPOUser -Site $SiteURL -LoginName $UserID
```

But I have multiple site collections that it needs to find that user in:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Projecten
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/PFO
```

How can I do this using a `for` loop so it finds the user in each site collection?

Answer (score 2):

Already figured it out:

```
$UserID="j.doe@contoso.nl"

$sitecollectios = @("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Extranet","https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso","https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Projecten","https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/PFO","https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/beheer","https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Intranet")

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential

#Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Site

Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credential $cred

foreach ($collectie in $sitecollectios)
{ 
    Get-SPOUser -Site $collectie -LoginName $UserID
}
```

Comment: As an aside: I suggest avoiding `@(...)` for array literals; e.g., instead of `@('a', 'b')`, use just `'a', 'b'`. Not only is `@(...)` unnecessary, it is inefficient in PowerShell versions up to 5.0, but - more importantly - it invites conceptual confusion by falsely suggesting that it _constructs_ arrays. For more information, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375).