# Change JSON property to an array if not an array powershell

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-core

I have a JSON that I want to check if it is an array, if not, I want to update the JSON and change it to an array

```
{
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "123"
    }],
 "address": {
    "type": "home",
    "name": "what",
    "description": "",
    "adi:water": {
      "type": "comp",
      "location": "grass"
    },
    "att": [
      {
        "name": "cat",
        "type": "int"
      },
      {
        "name": "ds",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}

#For example address is not an array, I want to change so address is an array of one single object
```

Code so far

```
$File = ((Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -path Test.json -Raw)

$File = $File| ConvertFrom-Json
$File.address = $File.address | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty streets #This line changes it to an object instead of an array
```

I want the address to be an array. Can I do that in powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) and reassign the `address` property value by enclosing it in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), to ensure that it is an array (if it already *is* an array, nothing changes<sup>[1]</sup>):

```
@'
{
  "Customer": [
      {
          "id": "123"
      }
  ],
  "address": {
      "type": "home",
      "name": "what",
      "description": "",
      "adi:water": {
          "type": "comp",
          "location": "grass"
      },
      "att": [
          {
              "name": "cat",
              "type": "int"
          },
          {
              "name": "ds",
              "type": "string"
          }
      ]
  }
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    $_.address = @($_.address | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty streets)
    $_ 
  } |
    ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```

<sup>Note the stand-alone `$_` statement after the assignment: it ensures that (modified) input object is also *output* (to the next pipeline segment), using PowerShell's *implicit output feature* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375).</sup>

**Note**: **[`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json)** limits the serialization depth to `2` by default, hence `-Depth 4` was used above to prevent data loss. In general, keep in mind that **you may have to pass a `-Depth` argument to `ConvertTo-Json` prevent data loss** - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).<sup>[2]</sup>

The above yields the following, showing that the `address` property is now an array:

```json
{
  "Customer": [
    {
      "id": "123"
    }
  ],
  "address": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "name": "what",
      "description": "",
      "adi:water": {
        "type": "comp",
        "location": "grass"
      },
      "att": [
        {
          "name": "cat",
          "type": "int"
        },
        {
          "name": "ds",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

<sup>[1] Technically, a (shallow) *copy* of an existing array is created, but that doesn't make any difference here.

To learn more about the `@()` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375).</sup>

<sup>[2] This requirement is cumbersome and easy to miss, but hasn't been changed for the sake of backward compatibility. However, **PowerShell version 7.1 will at least emit a *warning*** when the (possibly default) `-Depth` value is insufficient: see [this PR](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/13692) and the associated discussion in [GitHub issue #8393](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8393).

Also, the issue may be revisited in the context of moving the implementation of the JSON cmdlets from the Newtonsoft.Json library to the new(ish) built-in `System.Text.Json` API, at some point after v7.1, which will inevitably entail breaking changes - see [this PR](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/11198).</sup>