# Why does an array behave differently when directly assigned or retrieved from get-content

Tags: arrays, powershell, formatting

Here's something I don't understand.

When I define a variable:

```
$v = [byte]2, [byte]3
```

and check its type:

```
$v.getType().name
```

I get

```
Object[]
```

I then format `$v`:

```
'{0} {1}' -f $v
```

which prints

```
2 3
```

Now, if I get a file's first two bytes:

```
$f = (get-content 'xyz.txt' -encoding byte -readCount 2 -totalCount 2)
```

and check its type:

```
$f.getType().name
```

I get the same type as before: `Object[]`.

However, unlike with `$v`, I cannot format `$f`:

```
'{0} {1}' -f $f
```

I get the error message *Error formatting a string: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the*, although the length of the array is 2:

```
$f.length
```

returns

```
2
```

I don't understand why this is and would appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The **behavior should be considered a *bug* in the `-f` operator**; it is present as of v7.1 and reported in [GitHub issue #14355](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14355); it does *not* affect other operators with array operands, such as `-split` or `-in`.
- The **workaround** is to cast `$f` to `[array]` or, if creating a *copy* of the array is acceptable, `@($f)`:

```
'abc' > xyz.txt

$f = get-content 'xyz.txt' -encoding byte -readCount 2 -totalCount 2

'{0} {1}' -f ([array] $f)
```

Note: Using `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) - `... - @($f)` - as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) notes - is the even simpler option, but do note that using `@()` involves *cloning* (creating a shallow copy of) the array, whereas the `[array]` cast in this case does not.

The alternative is to apply the `[array]` cast as a *type constraint* (by placing it to the left of the `$f = ...` assignment):

```
'abc' > xyz.txt

[array] $f = (get-content 'xyz.txt' -encoding byte -readCount 2 -totalCount 2)

'{0} {1}' -f $f
```

Note:

- In PowerShell [Core] v6+, you must use `-AsByteStream` in lieu of `-Encoding Byte`.
- The problem can also be avoided if `-ReadCount 2` is omitted, but note that that decreases the performance of the command, because the bytes are then emitted one by one; that is, with `-ReadCount 2 -TotalCount 2` a *single* object is emitted that is a 2-byte array *as a whole*, whereas just `-TotalCount 2` emits the *individual bytes*, *one by one* to the pipeline, in which case it is then the PowerShell engine itself that collects these bytes in an `[object[]]` array for the assignment.
- Note that applying `@()` *directly* to the command - `@(get-content ...)` - would *not* work in this case, because `@()`, due to parameter combination `-ReadCount 2 -TotalCount 2`, receives a *single* output object that *happens to be an array as a whole* and therefore wraps that single object in another array. This results in a single-element array whose element is the original 2-element array of bytes; for more information about how `@(...)` works, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375).

---

**Background information:**

The **problem is an invisible `[psobject]` wrapper** around each array returned by `Get-Content -ReadCount` (just *one* in this case), which unexpectedly causes the `$f` array **passed to `-f`** not to be recognized as such.

Note that PowerShell's other array-based operators, such as `-in` and `-replace`, are *not* affected.

The wrapper can be bypassed in two ways:

- `$f.psobject.BaseObject`
- casting to `[array]`, as shown at the top.

Note:

- Generally, **output objects produced by *cmdlets*** - as opposed to output produced by *PowerShell code* - **have *generally* invisible `[psobject]` wrappers**; mostly, they are benign, because PowerShell usually just cares about the .NET object being *wrapped*, not about the wrapper, but on occasion problems arise, such as in this case - see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579) for a discussion of the problem and other contexts in which it manifests.
- In order to **test if a given object has a `[psobject]` wrapper**, use `-is [psobject]`; e.g.:

```sh
$var = 1
$var -is [psobject] # -> $false

$var = Write-Output 1
$var -is [psobject] # -> $true, due to use of a cmdlet.

# You can also test command output directly.
(Write-Output 1) -is [psobject]  # -> $true
```