# Powershell local array re-initialization

Tags: powershell, local-variables

I found an error in one of my scripts, it looks like PowerShell (version 2.0) does not re-initialize local arrays when entering a function again. Here is a minimalist example:

```
function PrintNumbersUntilX {
    param (
        [ Parameter( Mandatory = $true ) ] $X
    )
    $Number = 0
    while( $Number -le $X ) {
        Write-Host $Number
        $Number++
    }
}

function PrintNumbersUntilY {
    param (
        [ Parameter( Mandatory = $true ) ] $Y
    )
    $Number = ( , 0 )
    while( $Number[ 0 ] -le $Y ) {
        Write-Host $Number[ 0 ]
        $Number[ 0 ]++
    }
}

function Main {
    Write-Host 'X-3: '
    PrintNumbersUntilX -X 3
    Write-Host 'X-12: '
    PrintNumbersUntilX -X 12
    Write-Host 'Y-3: '
    PrintNumbersUntilY -Y 3
    Write-Host 'Y-12: '
    PrintNumbersUntilY -Y 12
}

Main
```

Output (linebreaks replaced with space):

```
X-3:  0 1 2 3 X-12:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 Y-3:  0 1 2 3 Y-12:  4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

PrintNumbersUntilX  works as I would expect from a local variable but PrintNumbersUntilY does not reset (reinitialize) $Number

Is this bug fixed in later versions, or is this a 'feature', if so what is it called, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: This is specific to 2.0 (repro'able in later versions by starting with `-version 2` but not otherwise), but even there it's fixed by using `$Number = @(0)` (which is the proper way of declaring an array, even if the comma trick is occasionally required to prevent unrolling in more complex cases).

Comment: Good point about the bug being v2-specific, @JeroenMostert, but `@(...)` isn't the proper way to declare an array in PowerShell, because it is generally unnecessary and can invite conceptual confusion - please see my answer. `, 0` isn't a trick in this case, it is the proper use of the unary form of the array-construction operator to construct a single-element array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around it in 2.0 by using an explicit array subexpression `@()` to initialize `$Number`:

```
$Number = @( , 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are aware of it, but let's be clear that the behavior observed is clearly **a - pretty serious bug - in version 2.0 of Windows PowerShell**:

- Seemingly, assignment of a *directly constructed single-element array* to a local variable is "optimized" away in subsequent calls to a given script or function.
- **If at all possible, consider upgrading your PowerShell version**: v2.0 of Windows PowerShell was released in October 2009; the current version is v5.1.

  - v2.0 will definitely *not* see any bug fixes, whereas v5.1 - which is the last ever ***Windows PowerShell*** version - is **no longer actively developed**, but *may* see bug fixes - depending on the severity of a given bug.
  - By contrast the cross-platform [PowerShell (Core) v6+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition is Windows PowerShell's *successor*, which is **actively developed and maintained**.

---

**Workarounds:**

**Option 1:** **Use `@(...)`**, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) in lieu of the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-):

```
$Number = @( 0 )
```

This is a simplified, perhaps less obscure version of [Mathias R. Jessen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67300193/45375).

To be clear:

- **Your approach to constructing the single-element array - `, 0` - which works correctly in v3+, is *conceptually preferable***, because - unlike the `,` operator - **`@(...)` doesn't actually *construct* arrays**, it "guarantees" them, loosely speaking: That is, `@( @( 0 ) )` and `@( , 0 )` are the same as `@( 0 )` and result in a (non-nested) single-element array. By contrast, `, , 0` indeed constructs a *nested* array (a single-element array whose element is another single-element array whose element is `0`).
- **`@(...)` was never meant to be used for declaring *array literals***: Its purpose is to *collect the output from the enclosed command or expression* in a newly constructed `[object[]]` array, *even if only one object was output*, so as to ensure that *situationally* single-object output from the pipeline is still treated *as an array* (given that single-object output is by default collected *as-is*, without an array wrapper).

  - In PowerShell versions up to v5.0, using `@(...)` with an array literal was not only *unnecessary*, but *inefficient*: An *extra* array was created behind the scenes, based on the mechanism described.
  - Because the "off-label" use of `@(...)` for array initialization was very widespread, v5.1 introduced an optimization: `@(...)` was effectively optimized away behind the scenes in expression such as `@( 1, 2 )`, making it effectively the same as `1, 2`
  - It is precisely the *absence* of this optimization that makes the `@( 0 )` workaround effective in v2.0: because the evaluation is deferred until runtime, the buggy assignment "optimization" isn't performed.
- See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375) for more information about `@(...)`

**Option 2:** ***Type-constrain* the variable** as an array, which with strong typing `[int[]]` even improves efficiency (though the impact may be negligible):

```sh
[array] $Number = 0 # Note: "," isn't even needed then; constructs [object[]] array
   
# Or, more efficiently, with strong typing:
# (The above constructs an object[] array in which value types must be boxed.)
[int[]] $Number = 0
```