# How to invoke a function from within a powershell script?

Tags: arrays, powershell, path, scripting, console

How do I print a list of [files](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2449030&seqNum=11) by invoking `Get-FilesByDate` from within the `files.ps1` script itself?

```
$ pwsh files.ps1 
Get-FilesByDate
txt
1
1
/home/thufir/

$ cat files.ps1 

Function Get-FilesByDate
{
 Param(
  [string[]]$fileTypes,
  [int]$month,
  [int]$year,
  [string[]]$path)
   Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include $filetypes -Recurse |
   Where-Object {
   $_.lastwritetime.month -eq $month -AND $_.lastwritetime.year -eq $year }
} #end function Get-FilesByDate

Write-Output Get-FilesByDate("txt",1,1,"/home/thufir/")
```

Additionally, or alternately, populate an array with the file names?  Any and all files, or `txt`.

Answer (score 1):

`Write-Output` is rarely needed, because **you can rely on PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior**:

```
# By neither redirecting nor piping nor capturing the output from 
# this call, what it returns is *implicitly* output.
# Note the absence of parentheses and the separation of arguments with whitespace.
Get-FilesByDate "txt" 1 1 "/home/thufir/"
```

Note how the **arguments must be passed *without parentheses*** around the argument list and **separated by *whitespace***, not with the pseudo method syntax you've attempted.
In other words: **PowerShell commands (cmdlets, function, scripts, aliases) are invoked *like shell commands*, not like methods in C#.**

---

In order to **pass the output from a command as an *argument*** to another command:

- enclose the command in `(...)` or
- to ensure that the output is treated as an *array*, enclose it in `@(...)` or
- to pass the output from *multiple* statements, enclose them in `$(...)` (or `@(...)`)

Thus, in order to use `Write-Output` explicitly (which, as stated, isn't necessary), you'd have to write:

```
Write-Output (Get-FilesByDate "txt" 1 1 "/home/thufir/")
```

---

To **populate an array with the output from `Get-FilesByDate`**:

```
$files = @(Get-FilesByDate "txt" 1 1 "/home/thufir/")
```

The `@(...)` ensures that `$files` receives an array even if the function happens to return only a *single* file; alternatively, you could *type-constrain* the variable and thereby ensure that it is an array:

```
[array] $files = Get-FilesByDate "txt" 1 1 "/home/thufir/"
```

Note, however, that **explicit use of arrays is often not necessary** in PowerShell (since version 3), because **even scalars (single values) implicitly act like arrays** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375).

---

Further reading:

- PowerShell's parsing modes: the [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) help topic.
- How PowerShell parses command arguments: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).