# Count columns of an imported Excel workbook - count a given object's properties

Tags: powershell, reflection

I have imported an Excel sheet into PowerShell by using this [module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.4.0):

I want to count the number of columns so I used the below function:

```
 $columns = @(Import-Excel -Path "D:\Qlik\AccessRules\Roster\RosterTest-Jan.xlsx" -StartRow 1 -EndRow 1 -NoHeader)
```

Now the array has 51 keys I presume. But how do I count it? No matter what I try, all I see is 1.

I tried:

```
$columns.Count
$columns.PSObject.BaseObject.Count
```

Nothing works, any ideas please.

Comment: The title is IMO too specific, should be Count properties of an object.  `$ColumnCount = ($CountColumns | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Count`

Comment: Good point, @LotPings - I've generalized the title. Your solution works, but is a bit heavy-handed.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**:

```bash
@($columns.psobject.properties).Count
```

---

What you're looking for is the **count of an object's *properties***, which can be done via the **`.psobject.properties` collection**, which is **available on *any* object in PowerShell**  - and therefore also on the `[pscustomobject]` instances returned by `Import-Excel` - as a *reflection* feature that allows you to inspect a given object's properties.

***Counting* the properties is tricky**, because **the specific collection data type returned by `.psobject.properties`** - `[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoIntegratingCollection[System.Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo]]` - unexpectedly **implements neither a `.Count` nor a `.Length` property**.

The **workaround is to use `@(...)`**, the array subexpression operator, to collect the individual properties *as a regular PowerShell array* (`[object[]]`), on which you can then call `.Count`:

```bash
@($columns.psobject.properties).Count
```

See [GitHub issue #9155](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9155), which asks for a `.Count` property to be implemented on the collection returned by `.psobject.properties` so as to render this workaround unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have done it.

```
$columns = (($columns[0].psobject.properties).Count).Count
```

Comment: While this solution works, it is conceptually obscure: (a) The `[0]` is unnecessary, because `$columns` contains only a _single_ object, a `[pscustomobject]` instance. (b) The inner `.Count` effectively uses [member enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to call `.Count` on _each property definition_, which effectively returns an _array_ containing `1` for each property, given that [PowerShell (since v3) implements a `.Count` property even on _scalars_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) (single objects). It is that array's elements that the outer `.Count` counts.