# IF contains more than one string do "this" else "this"

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, count, scalar

Trying to make a script that request more info (group Id) if there are SCOM groups with identical names:

```
function myFunction {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string[]]$ObjectName
    )

    foreach ($o in $ObjectName) {
        $p = Get-SCOMGroup -DisplayName "$o" | select DisplayName
        <#
        if ($p contains more than one string) {
            "Request group Id"
        } else {
            "do this"
        }
        #>            
    }
}
```

Need help with the functionality in the comment block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the value in an array subexpression `@()` and count how many entries it has:

```
if(@($p).Count -gt 1){"Request group Id"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer complements [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55396946/45375).

#### Counting the number of objects returned by a command:

- Mathias' answer shows a **robust, PowerShell v2-compatible solution** based on the **[array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--), `@()`**.

  ```
    # @() ensures that the output of command ... is treated as an array,
    # even if the command emits only *one* object.
    # You can safely call .Count (or .Length) on the result to get the count.
    @(...).Count
  ```
- In **PowerShell v3 or higher**, you **can treat scalars like collections**, so that **using just `(...).Count` is typically enough**. (A scalar is a single objects, as opposed to a collections of objects).

  ```
    # Even if command ... returns only *one* object, it is safe
    # to call .Count on the result in PSv3+
    (...).Count
  ```

**These methods are *typically*, but not always interchangeable**, as discussed below.

---

- **Choose `@(...).Count`**, if:

  - you must remain PSv2-compatible
  - you want to count output from *multiple* commands (separated with `;` or newlines)
  - for commands that output entire collections *as a single object* (which is rare), you want to *count such collections as `1` object*.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - more generally, if you need to ensure that the command output is returned as a bona fide *array*, though note that it is invariably of type `[object[]]`; if you need a *specific element type*, use a cast (e.g., `[int[]]`), but note that you then don't strictly need the `@(...)`; e.g.,
    `[int[]] (...)` will do - unless you want to prevent enumeration of collections output as single objects.
- **Choose `(...).Count`**, if:

  - only *one* command's output must be counted
  - for commands that output entire collections *as a single object*, you want to *count the individual elements* of such collections; that is, `(...)` forces enumeration of command output.<sup>[2]</sup>
  - for counting the elements of commands's output *already stored in a variable* - though, of course, you can then simply *omit* the `(...)` and use `$var.Count`

**Caveat**: Due to [a longstanding *bug*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798) (still present as of PowerShell Core 6.2.0), accessing `.Count` on a *scalar* fails while `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher is in effect - use `@(...)` in that case, but note that you may have to force enumeration.

To demonstrate the difference in behavior with respect to (rare) commands that output collections *as single objects*:

```
PS> @(Write-Output -NoEnumerate (1..10)).Count 
1  # Array-as-single-object was counted as *1* object

PS> (Write-Output -NoEnumerate (1..10)).Count 
10  # Elements were enumerated.
```

---

**Performance considerations**:

- **If a command's output is *directly* counted, `(...)` and `@(...)` perform about the same**:

  ```
    $arr = 1..1e6  # Create an array of 1 million integers.

    { (Write-Output $arr).Count }, { @(Write-Output $arr).Count } | ForEach-Object {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Command = "$_".Trim()
        Seconds = '{0:N3}' -f (Measure-Command $_).TotalSeconds
      }
    }
  ```

  - Sample output, from a single-core Windows 10 VM (the absolute timings aren't important, only that the numbers are virtually the same):

    ```
        Command                    Seconds
        -------                    -------
        (Write-Output $arr).Count  0.352
        @(Write-Output $arr).Count 0.365
    ```
- **By contrast, for large collections *already stored in a variable*, `@(...)` introduces substantial overhead**, because the collection is recreated as a (new) array (as noted, you can just `$arr.Count`):

  ```
    $arr = 1..1e6  # Create an array of 1 million integers.

    { ($arr).Count }, { @($arr).Count } | ForEach-Object {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Command = "$_".Trim()
        Seconds = '{0:N3}' -f (Measure-Command $_).TotalSeconds
      }
    }
  ```

  - Sample output; note how the `@(...)` solution is about 7 times slower:

    ```
        Command       Seconds
        -------       -------
        ($arr).Count  0.009
        @($arr).Count 0.067
    ```

---

**Coding-style considerations**:

The following applies in situations where `@(...)` and `(...)` are functionally equivalent (and either perform the same or when performance is secondary), i.e., when you're ***free to choose* which construct to use**.

**Mathias recommends `@(...).Count`**, stating in a comment:

> There's another reason to explicitly wrap it in this context - *conveying intent*, i.e., "We don't know if `$p` is a scalar or not, hence this construct".

**My vote is for `(...).Count`**:

Once you understand that PowerShell (v3 or higher) treats scalars as collections with count 1 on demand, you're free to take advantage of that knowledge without needing to reflect the distinction between a scalar and an array in the *syntax*:

- When writing code, this means **you needn't worry about whether a given command *situationally* may return a scalar rather than a collection** (which is common in PowerShell, where capturing output from a command with a *single* output object captures that object as-is, whereas *2 or more* output objects result in an *array*).
- As a beneficial side effect, the **code becomes more concise** (and sometimes faster).

Example:

```
# Call Get-ChildItem twice, and, via Select-Object, limit the 
# number of output objects to 1 and 2, respectively.
1..2 | ForEach-Object {

  # * In the 1st iteration, $var becomes a *scalar* of type [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
  # * In the 2nd iteration, $var becomes an *array* with 
  #   2 elements of type [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
  $var = Get-ChildItem -Directory / | Select-Object -First $_

  # Treat $var as a collection, which in PSv3+ works even
  # if $var is a scalar:
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Count = $var.Count
    FirstElement = $var[0]
    DataType = $var.GetType().Name
  }

}
```

The above yields:

```
Count FirstElement  DataType
----- ------------  --------
    1 /Applications DirectoryInfo
    2 /Applications Object[]
```

That is, even the scalar object of type `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` reported its `.Count` sensibly as `1` and allowed access to "its first element" with `[0]`.

For more about the unified handling of scalars and collections, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375).

---

<sup>[1] E.g., `@(Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2).Count` is `1`, because the `Write-Output` command outputs a *single* object - the array `1, 2` - _as a whole. Because only a single object is output, `@(...)` wraps that object in an array, resulting in `, (1, 2)`, i.e. a single-element array whose first and only element is itself an array.</sup>

<sup>[2] E.g., `(Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2).Count` is `2`, because even though the `Write-Output` command outputs the array as a single object, that array is used as-is. That is, the whole expression is equivalent to `(1, 2).Count`. More generally, if a command inside `(...)` outputs just *one* object, that object is used as-is; if it outputs *multiple* objects, they are collected in a regular PowerShell array (of type `[object[]]`) - this is the same behavior you get when capturing command output via a *variable assignment* (`$captured = ...`).</sup>