# Properties not appearing in the Get-Member cmdlet and registering values when put in . notation

Tags: powershell

Properties not appearing in the Get-Member cmdlet and registering values when put in . notation

```
Running
Get-ChildItem | Get-member
TypeName: System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Name                      MemberType     Definition
----                      ----------     ----------
LinkType                  CodeProperty   System.String LinkType{get=GetLinkType;}
Mode                      CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}….
```

There is no Count property, for the GCI cmdlet there is a count property for the Measure-object cmdlet, as seen.

```
PS C:\Users\NiceTry5> measure-object | get-member




TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
Average     Property   System.Nullable[double] Average {get;set;}
Count       Property   int Count {get;set;}
```

Why then does the count property of the measure-object cmdlet register a value for the GCI cmdlet?

```
PS C:\Users\NiceTry5> (GCI).count
32
```

I believe the count property must belong to some sort of superset that contains the GCI cmdlet, and is hidden when running Get-member, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **`Get-Member` operates on the *individual objects* received via the pipelin**e and returns information about the *distinct* types among them.

  - Therefore, with the output from a `Get-ChildItem` command targeting the file-system, you'll see information about types `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` and/or `System.IO.FileInfo` - and these types have no `.Count` property.
  - In order to inspect a collection-like type itself (rather than its elements), pass it to 
    `Get-Member`'s `-InputObject` parameter instead of using the pipeline; e.g, 
    `Get-Member -InputObject (Get-ChildItem)`.
- **`(...)` around a command that outputs *multiple* objects implicitly collects these objects in an `[object[]]` array**, and any array has a `.Count` property, by virtue of the `IList` interface it implements.

  - That said, **PowerShell (since v3) *implicitly* provides a `.Count` property even on *scalars*, in an effort to unify the handling of scalars and  collections**; e.g., `(Get-Date).Count` yields `1`, as do `'foo'.Count` and `(42).Count` (sic) - however, 
    **`Get-Member` does *not* show this implicit `.Count` property.**

    - You can even use *indexing* (`[...]`) with scalars so as to treat them as a *single-element array*; e.g., `(42)[0]` is the same as `42` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) for more information (a notable exception is `[string]`, because that type itself defines indexing as accessing the individual *characters* in the string; e.g, `'foo'[0]` is `'f'`)
    - Such implicitly available members - which aren't native to the .NET type at hand - are calle [*intrinsic* members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members).

---

**Notable pitfalls** :

- **Using the *implicit* `.Count` property *fails* when `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher is in effect**:

  - e.g., `Set-StrictMode -Version 2; (42).Count` fails with `The property 'Count' cannot be found on this object.`
  - This problematic behavior is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798).
- **In *Windows PowerShell*** (whose latest and *final* version is 5.1), **`[pscustomobject]` instances do *not* have a `.Count` property, due to a *bug***, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68355717/45375) - this has been corrected in *PowerShell (Core, v6+)*.
- **A collection-like type that doesn't itself have a `.Count` property, e.g. a lazy enumerable, results in `.Count` being called *on each individual element***, due to [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375):

  - e.g.,`[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('.').Count` - because `EnumerateFiles()` returns a lazily enumerated `[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string]]` instance that therefore cannot have a `.Count` property - calls `.Count` *on each path* that is enumerated, resulting in an *array of `1`s*, because each individual path - as a scalar - has a count of `1`.