# Why is PSCustomObject being populated with individual characters instead of a single string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, pscustomobject

I am trying to learn PowerShell by translating an old batch script that I made for converting videos using FFmpeg.

That has almost nothing to do with the issue at hand, I believe.

This is the code snippet giving me trouble:

```bsh
[string]$FileList              = (Get-Clipboard).Split("`n")
[int]$Counter               = 0

$List                  = @(ForEach ($i in $FileList)
{
    [PSCustomObject]
   @{
        VideoHeight = (ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of csv=s=x:p=0 "$i")
        VideoDuration = (ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of csv=s=x:p=0 "$i")
    }
    $Counter++
})
```

Store in `$FileList` the list of files from the Clipboard separated by a new line.

Store in `$Counter` the integer `0`.

For each item in `$FileList`, create a new object containing the item's height and duration and add 1 to `$Counter`.

Seems straight-forward, right? Here's the catch: if there is only one file with a height of 1080 in `$FileList`, `$List.VideoHeight[0]` will return only `1` but if there is at least two files in `$FileList`, `$List.VideoHeight[0]` will return `1080`.

Command line output:

```
Single File
$List.VideoHeight:
1080
$List.VideoHeight[0]:
1
```

```
Multiple Files
$List.VideoHeight:
1080
1080
720
$List.VideoHeight[0]:
1080
```

Any ideas what is happening here? I am stuck.

Comment: As an aside: I assume `[string]$FileList` is meant to be `[string[]]$FileList` - otherwise, your `foreach` loop won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$List[0].VideoHeight`, not `$List.VideoHeight[0]`.

After all, from a conceptual standpoint, you want to get the `.VideoHeight` value of the first list item (`$List[0]`), not the first element of the whole list's video-height values (`$List.VideoHeight`).<sup>[1]</sup>

---

The reason it works with *multiple* items in `$List` is that PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) then returns an *array* of `.VideoHeight` property values, where indexing with `[0]` works as expected.

The reason it doesn't work as expected with a *single* item in `$List` is that then only a *scalar* (single) `.VideoHeight` property value is returned, and that scalar is of type `[string]`. Indexing into a single string returns the *individual characters* in the string, which is what you saw.

Simple demonstration:

```sh
PS> ([pscustomobject] @{ VideoHeight = '1080' }).VideoHeight[0]
1  # [char] '1', the first character in string '1080'
```

vs.

```sh
PS> ([pscustomobject] @{ VideoHeight = '1080' }, 
     [pscustomobject] @{ VideoHeight = '1081' }).VideoHeight[0]
1080  # [string] '1080', the first element in array '1080', '1081'
```

So there are two factors contributing to the unexpected behavior:

- PowerShell's member-access enumeration applies the same logic as when pipeline output is collected: If the collection whose members are being enumerated happens to have just *one* element, that member (property) value is returned *as-is*; only 2 or more elements result in an `[object[]]` *array* of values.

  - It is somewhat unfortunate that member-access enumeration behaves this way; the behavior can be even more surprising when the property values are arrays themselves: the resulting arrays are then *concatenated* instead of becoming individual subarrays in the output array - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6802).
- The standard behavior of the .NET [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String) type (`[string]`), which allows direct indexing of the characters that make up the string (e.g. `"foo"[0]` yielding `[char] 'f'`).

  - Strictly speaking, it is whatever language consumes the type that implements the `[...]` indexer syntax, which is a form of syntactic sugar; the underlying type only has a *parameterized property* named `Chars`, which both C# and PowerShell expose more conveniently via `[...]`.
  - In the case of `[string]`, however, this unfortunately conflicts with PowerShell's unified handling of collections and scalars, where *usually* `$scalar[0]` is the same as `$scalar` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) for background information.

---

<sup>[1] *If* collecting the values of all `$List` `.VideoHeight` property values *consistently* returned an array (why it doesn't is explained in the second section), the two statements would be *functionally* equivalent, though `$List[0].VideoHeight` is still preferable *for efficiency* (no intermediate array of property values must be constructed) and also for the sake of avoiding potential member-name conflicts, which *member-access enumeration* inherently entails - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7445).</sup>