# How to get the first row from a PowerShell datatable

Tags: powershell, datatable

In PowerShell, if `$dt` is a datatable, I am used to using `foreach()` to do row-by-row operations. For example...

```
foreach ($tmpRow in $dt) {
   Write-Host $tmpRow.blabla
}
```

I just want to get the first row (of `n` columns). I could introduce a counter `$i` and just break the foreach loop on the first iteration, but that seems clunky. Is there a more direct way of achieving this?

Comment: `$dt.Rows[0]` ?

Comment: Or: `$dt | Select -First 1 | Foreach { ...`

Answer (score 5):

- **For a collection (array) that is *already in memory***, **use *indexing***, namely `[0]`:

  - Note: ***Normally*, `$dt[0]` should suffice**, but ***in this case* the index must be applied to the `.Rows` property**, as [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) advises:

    - `$dt.Rows[0].blabla`
  - Given that PowerShell automatically *enumerates* a [`System.Data.DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataTable) by enumerating the [`System.Data.DataRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataRow) instances stored in its `.Rows` property - both in the pipeline and in a `foreach` loop, as in your code - **the need to specify `.Rows` *explicitly* for indexing is surprising**.

    - With `$dt` containing a `System.Data.DataTable` instance, `$dt[0]` is actually the same as just `$dt` itself, because PowerShell in this context considers `$dt` a *single object*, and generally supports indexing even into such single objects, in the interest of *unified treatment of scalars and arrays* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) for background information.
- **For *command output***, use [`Select-Object -First 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object). Using the example of [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd)

  - `(Invoke-SqlCommand ... | Select-Object -First 1).blabla`
  - Note: Since `Invoke-SqlCommand` by default outputs individual `System.Data.DataRow` instances (one by one), you can directly access property `.blabla` on the result.
  - The advantage of using **`Select-Object -First 1`** is that **short-circuits the pipeline** and returns once the first output object has been received, obviating the need to retrieve further objects.

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell automatically enumerates all rows when you pipe a `DataTable`, so you could pipe it to `Select-Object -First 1`:

```
# set up sample table
$dt = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('ID', [int])
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('Name', [string])

# initialize with 2 rows
[void]$dt.Rows.Add(1, "Clive")
[void]$dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mathias")

# enumerate only 1 row
foreach ($tmpRow in $dt |Select-Object -First 1) {
   Write-Host "Row with ID '$($tmpRow.ID)' has name '$($tmpRow.Name)'"
}
```

Expected screen buffer output:

```
Row with ID '1' has name 'Clive'
```