# Powershell only outputting first character

Tags: powershell

I have the following dataset:

```
 id|selectedquery|
 1|SELECT fieldX FROM tableA|
 2|SELECT fieldY FROM tableB|
```

that dataset is used in the following code

```
$rows=($dataSet.Tables | Select-Object -Expand Rows)
$i=0
foreach ($row in $rows)
{
#Write-Output $rows.selectquery[$i].length
$query =   $rows.selectquery[$i]
#Write-Output $rows.selectquery[$i]
--doing some stuff--
$i++
}
```

Often `$rows.selectquery[$i]` only gives me the first character of the value in the field `selectedquery` being the 'S'.

When I remove the `[$i]` from `$rows.selectquery` it gives me (understandably) multiple records back. If I then put the [$i] back after `$rows.selectquery[$i]` things woerk fine.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Ofcourse!!! Please put that as an answer ? You deserve the points and I deserve a punishment

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a foreach with `$row` but referencing the selectquery with [`i]` rather than `[$row]` ?

Comment: OPtherwise it gives me all the records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to reference the `SelectQuery` property on either `$row` or `$rows[$i]` - *not* the entire `$rows` collection:

```
$row.SelectQuery
# or
$rows[$i].SelectQuery
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68214233/45375) shows the best way to solve your particular problem.

As for **what happened**:

You - inadvertently - used PowerShell's **[member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)** feature when you used `$rows.selectquery`; that is, even though `$rows` is a *collection* that *itself* has no `.selectquery` property, PowerShell accessed that property on *every element* of the collection and returned the resulting values *as an array*.

The **pitfall** is that **if the collection only has *one* element, the return value is *not* an array** - it is just the one and only element's property value *itself*.

While this is analogous to how the *pipeline* operates (a single output object is captured by itself if assigned to a variable, while two or more are implicitly collected in an array), it is somewhat counterintuitive in the context of member-access enumeration:

- In other words, `$collection.SomeProperty` is equivalent to `$collection | ForEach-Object { $_.SomeProperty }` and *not*, as would make more sense, because it *always* returns an array (collection), `$collection.ForEach('SomeProperty')`
- [GitHub issue #6802](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6802) discusses this problem.

While this behavior is often unproblematic, because PowerShell offers *unified handling of scalars and collections* (e.g. `(42)[0]`, is the same as `42` itself; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375)), a **problem arises if the single value returned happens to be a *string*, because indexing into a string returns *its characters***.

- **Workaround**: Cast to `[array]` before applying the index:

  - `([array] $rows.selectquery)[0]`

A simple **example**:

```sh
# Multi-element array.
[array] $rows1 = [pscustomobject] @{ selectquery = 'foo' },
                 [pscustomobject] @{ selectquery = 'bar' }

# Single-element array:
[array] $rows2 = [pscustomobject] @{ selectquery = 'baz' }

# Contrast member-access enumeration + index access between the two:
[pscustomobject] @{
  MultiElement = $rows1.selectquery[0]
  SingleElement = $rows2.selectquery[0]
  SinglElementWithWorkaround = ([array] $rows2.selectquery)[0]
}
```

The above yields the following:

```sh
MultiElement SingleElement SinglElementWithWorkaround
------------ ------------- --------------------------
foo                      b baz
```

As you can see, the multi-element array worked as expected, because the member-access enumeration returned an array too, while the single-element array resulted in *single string* `'baz'` being returned and `'baz'[0]` returns *its first character*, `'b'`.

Casting to `[array]` first avoids that problem (`([array] $rows2.selectquery)[0]`).

- Using `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) - `@($rows.selectquery)[0]` - is another option, but, for the sake of efficiency, it should only be used on *commands* (e.g., `@(Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt)[0]`) not *expressions*, as in the case at hand.)