# Two objects of different sizes and $null

Tags: string, powershell, pipeline, enumeration

My code below works in every instance except for if one object is `$null` and the other object has one item.  When that situation occurs the output becomes 1 letter like it is indexing and I am not sure why.
How do I combine the two objects to make a final report?

```
$ADGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $UserSam | Select-Object distinguishedName, name | Where-Object { ($_.distinguishedName -ne 'CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=com') }

#record AD groups
$ADResult = @()
if ($null -eq $ADGroups) {
    Write-Warning "No AD Groups"
    $ADResult = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        ADGroups                  = @()
        ADGroupsdistinguishedName = @()
    }
}
Else {
    $ADResult = $ADGroups | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ADGroups                  = $_.name
            ADGroupsdistinguishedName = $_.distinguishedName
        }
    }
}

#============= Now Google, get user groups and record
$GoogleGroups = gam print groups member $email members managers owners | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Record Google Groups
$GResult = @()
If ($null -eq $GoogleGroups) {
    Write-Warning "No Google Groups"
    $GResult = [PSCustomObject]@{
        GoogleGroups = @()
        Role         = @()
    }
}
Else {
    $group = $null
    $GResult = ForEach ($group in $GoogleGroups) {
        #this records what role the user had in the group(s)
        $GoogleMember = gam print group-members group $group.email members | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty email
        $Role = $null
        If ( $GoogleMember -contains $EMAIL) {
            $Role = 'Member'
        }
        Else {
            $GoogleManager = gam print group-members group $group.email managers | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty email
            If ($GoogleManager -contains $EMAIL) {
                $Role = 'Manager'
            }
            Else {
                $Role = 'Owner'
            }
        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            GoogleGroups = $group.email
            Role         = $role
        }
        $group = $null
    }
}

# ---------now report that will be dropped off at end
[int]$max = $ADResult.count
if ([int]$GResult.count -gt $max) { [int]$max = $GResult.count }

If ($max -eq 1 -or $max -eq 0) {
    $Result = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        PrimaryEmail                 = $email
        Title                        = $UserInfo.title
        Department                   = $UserInfo.Department
        Manager                      = $Manager
        ADGroupName                  = $ADResult.ADGroups
        ADGroupNameDistinguishedName = $ADResult.ADGroupsdistinguishedName
        GoogleGroup                  = $GResult.GoogleGroups
        Role                         = $GResult.role
        DateOfSeparation             = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")
        UserDistinguishedName        = $UserInfo.distinguishedName
        UserOU                       = $UserInfo.Ou
        PrimaryGroup                 = $UserInfo.primaryGroup.Split('=').Split(',')
    }
}
Else {
    $Result = for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{ 
            PrimaryEmail                 = $email
            Title                        = $UserInfo.title
            Department                   = $UserInfo.Department
            ADGroupName                  = $ADResult.ADGroups[$i]
            ADGroupNameDistinguishedName = $ADResult.ADGroupsdistinguishedName[$i]
            GoogleGroup                  = $GResult.GoogleGroups[$i]
            Role                         = $GResult.role[$i]
            DateOfSeparation             = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")
            UserDistinguishedName        = $UserInfo.distinguishedName
            UserOU                       = $UserInfo.Ou
            PrimaryGroup                 = $UserInfo.primaryGroup.Split('=').Split(',')[$i]
        }
    }
}


$Result | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\Groups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the abstract description of your problem:

You're seeing an **unfortunate asymmetry** in PowerShell:

- **In the *pipeline*, a `[string]` instance is considered *a single object***.

  ```sh
  PS> ('foo' | Measure-Object).Count
  1
  ```
- **With respect to *indexing*, it is considered *an array of characters***.

  ```sh
  PS> 'foo'[0]
  f
  ```

A general feature of capturing a PowerShell **pipeline**'s output is that **if a command *situationally*  outputs just a *single* object, that object is captured *as-is*, whereas *two or more* output objects result in a regular PowerShell *array***, of type `[object[]]`.

- ***Typically*, this isn't a problem, because PowerShell's unified handling of scalars and collections allows you to index even into a *scalar* (single object)**, i.e. to implicitly treat a single object *as if it were a single-element array*:

  ```sh
  PS> (Write-Output 42, 43)[0]
  42

  PS> (Write-Output 42)[0]
  42  # still OK, even though only *one* object was output; same as: (42)[0]
  ```
- However, **with a single `[string]` instance as the output it becomes a problem**, for the reasons stated above:

  ```sh
  PS> (Write-Output 'foo', 'bar')[0]
  foo # OK

  PS> (Write-Output 'foo')[0]
  f   # !! Indexing into a *single string* treats it as *character array*
  ```

The **same applies to values returned via [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)**, [perhaps surprisingly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68215551/45375) :

```sh
PS> (Get-Item $HOME, /).FullName[0]
C:\Users\Jdoe

PS> (Get-Item $HOME).FullName[0]
C # !! Indexing into a *single string* treats it as *character array*
```

**Workarounds**:

- Enclose the command of interest in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) so as to ensure that its output is always considered an *array*.

  ```sh
  PS> @(Write-Output 'foo')[0]
  foo # OK
  ```
- Alternatively, when capturing a command's output in a *variable*, type-constrain that variable to `[array]` (same as `[object[]]`) or a *strongly typed* array, `[string[]]`:

  ```sh
  PS> [array] $output = Write-Output 'foo'; $output[0]
  foo # OK
  ```

Comment: is it as simple as `ADGroupName = [array]$ADResult.ADGroups` or do I have to do that in the `foreach` loops ?

Comment: @dcaz, yes, `([array] $ADResult.ADGroups)[0]` reliably returns the first or only string in the value of `.ADGroups` - irrespective of whether it contains a single string or an array of strings; see also my update re _member enumeration_.

Comment: It worked. `ADGroupName = @($ADResult.ADGroups)[$i]` its important to note i had to  add `If ($max -ne 0) { $max = $max - 1 }` near the max to stop empty space.