# Select-Object -Unique returns String instead of String array

Tags: arrays, powershell, types, pipeline

This case only appears with arrays of the length one.

Example:

```
$array = @("55") 
$arrayAfterUnique = $array | Select-Object -Unique
```

So I want `$arrayAfterUnique` to be an array of length one.
However, `Select-Object` will make a string out of it.

Is there an easy workaround for this problem?

Comment: Yes - `$array | Select-Object -Unique` -> `@($array | Select-Object -Unique)`

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44035319/45375 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9701836/45375

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However Select-Object will make a string out of it

Not quite - `Select-Object` will return 0 or more *objects*, and depending on the number, the PowerShell runtime will decide whether the result is to be stored as a scalar or an array.

You can force the result to be an array regardless of how many objects are in the output, by using the array sub-expression operator `@()`:

```
$array = @("55") 
$arrayAfterUnique = @($array | Select-Object -Unique)
```

Comment: What will happen if  $array = @("55", "66")? Is it going to be a matrix then?

Comment: @Jenew: You'll get an `[object[]]` array (one-dimensional).

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58695411/45375), which explains the issue well:

**An alternative to [`@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--) is to *type-constrain* the result variable with `[array]`** placed to the *left* of the variable, in order to ensure that the collected result is *always* an array:

```
# Ensure that $arrayAfterUnique always contains an array.
[array] $arrayAfterUnique = 1, 1 | Select-Object -Unique
```

`[array]` is in effect the same as `[object[]]`, i.e., a regular PowerShell array.

If the output from the RHS command is a single value (scalar), that value is now automatically converted to a single-element array; with multiple output values, the `[object[]]` array implicitly created by PowerShell for collecting the outputs is stored as-is.

Note: Type-constraining a variable means that future assignments too must be of the locked-in type or convertible to it; e.g., later execution of `$arrayAfterUnique = 42` again converts integer `42` to a single-element array.

However, **it is often *not necessary* to distinguish between scalars and arrays**, because PowerShell allows you treat scalars *like* arrays, by given them a `.Count` property with value `1` and allowing *indexing* with `[0]` and `[-1]` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) for more information.

---

As for the *input* side:

**On sending arrays *to* the pipeline, PowerShell *enumerates* them** - that is, the elements are sent *one by one* to the command in the next pipeline segment.

Therefore,  *single-value* input is effectively the same as *single-element array* input.

That is, the following two commands behave identically:

```
# In both cases, Select-Object receives single value '55'
  '55'  | Select-Object -Unique   # single value
@('55') | Select-Object -Unique   # single-element array
```

**If you need to ensure that an array is sent *as a whole* to the pipeline**, precede it with `,` (the array-construction operator)<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
# Send array 1, 2 as a whole to ForEach-Object
# Note the need for (...) to clarify precedence.
, (1, 2) | ForEach-Object { $_.GetType().Name } # -> 'Object[]'

# Less efficient, but conceptually clearer alternative:
Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2
```

---

<sup>[1] This wraps the array in an auxiliary single-element helper array, and it is that helper array that PowerShell enumerates, therefore sending its one and only element - the original array - as-is through the pipeline.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. This helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom function to convert to Array [as shown here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/converting-to-array/).

```
function ToArray
{
  begin
  {
    $output = @()
  }
  process
  {
    $output += $_
  }
  end
  {
    return ,$output
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$array = @("55") 
$arrayAfterUnique = $array | Select-Object -Unique | ToArray
$arrayAfterUnique.GetType() # Returns System.Array
```

**Update:**

Worth mentioning, that this approach might have performance penalties as a new array is being created for every item due to use of `+-`.